# Sticky div in CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like a div to be pushed down (see "Search while I move the map" in the screenshot), to float above the map, but so that if I use any constants for `margin-top` or `top`, then that's relative to the parent div (map), not the browser window.

How can I do so? [Website link](https://waternearme.herokuapp.com/map) I have tried to add `position: relative;` to the parent `#map` but this is what I get (the map gets hidden):

[image]

This is my CSS code:

```
#map {
    #searchCheckboxContainer {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-table;
        white-space: nowrap;
        margin-top: 24px;  // sure, this works, but it's 24px *from the browser window*
        top: 0px;          // any way to make it relative to the parent div (map)?
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
    }

    #searchCheckboxContainer {
        height: 40px;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="map" v-cloak>
      <div id="searchCheckboxContainer">
        <div id="searchCheckbox">
            <input id="checkbox" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
              Search as I move the map
            </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="mapid"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Why not add `position: relative` to the `#map` element?

Comment: @disinfor That scrumbles everything up for reasons I don't know (e.g. everything turns white)

Comment: Then we need to see more code..since `position: absolute` positions an element within the bounds of the nearest parent with a `position` set.

Comment: @disinfor added code to question plus website link for those really curious. Thank you

Comment: @Cesare you would have to give `#map` a height and set you `z-index` on your search box div and `#mapid` div

Comment: Looking at your code, it's because all of the children elements of `#map` are absolutely positioned. Add `height: 100vh` to `#map` (along with `position: relative`) and then add a z-index to the `#searchCheckboxContainer` of 100.

Comment: if you don't want a scrollbar then remove the height of the header and padding-bottom from `#page-wrap` like this: `height: calc(100vh - 56px - 40px)`

Comment: @zgood you have a typo in `calc` :)

Comment: @disinfor fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding as an answer to avoid the comment noise:

All of the `#map` element children are positioned absolute. So, essentially they aren't in the normal document flow and will not affect the height of the `#map` div.

You need to add:

```
position: relative;
height: 100vh (or whatever)
```

To your `#map` div.

Then, to your `#searchCheckboxContainer`, add a `z-index: 100 //could be anything but that worked`

This will put the box above the map.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need it to look like that:

[image]

In this case you need to modify the following:

```
#map {
    position: relative;
    height: calc(100vh - 86px); // The height of header on mobile and you need to add responsive media queries to handle it.
}

#map #searchCheckboxContainer{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-table;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: auto;
    transform: none;
    background: #ffffff !important;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
}

#searchCheckbox .form-check-input{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}

#map #mapid{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I conceived it to be floating on the map, but +1 for the efforts